# What is the common accepted/ best performed method to classify trends and mean-reversion for fixed peroid?

Tags: mean-reversion, trends

I have knew some strategies only work on trends peroid, and other only works on mean-reversion peroid. But I didn't find how to classify trends and mean-reversion.
I wonder the best performed/verified research/paper on this topic, but searching google get a lot of stuffs, hard to verify which is good in real. So ask for advice from someone with experience.

Answer (score 1):

Up to interpretation, and specifics about this is generally not disclosed since it provides a real edge in trading. One common approach that use is Regime modelling using Hidden State Markov Models. There are several papers available on the topic, below are some suggestions:

- https://arxiv.org/pdf/2307.00459.pdf (good starter)
- https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4556048 (a bit advanced)

Answer (score 0):

It is true that there have been historical periods when trend following (tf)  methods worked particularly well and others where mean-reversion (mr) worked well. But to my knowledge there is no way to predict this ahead of time, such periods are only identified in retrospect.

For example in RiskNet, Aug 2023 we read: "After a stellar 2022, seesawing US Treasury yields in March [2023] led to sharp losses for many trend-following firms." You would think if the firms had a way to predict if the upcoming period was favorable for trend-following or not they would have avoided these losses. Most likely they did not know.

OTOH I remember tf pioneer Larry Hite saying in a lecture that he would reduce or even suspend his trend following trades if volatility was very high, because such periods were unfavorable for tf. But he didn't reveal the exact rule he followed, such trading rules are unlikely to be made public and cannot be evaluated. At best they give a clue to what criteria are used.